# Best practice methods to compare 2 regression models?

Tags: regression, model-comparison

I have two regression models that differ only by one thing: model 1 has one of the explanatory variables linear while model 2 takes the natural logarithm of it.

I would like to know, what are the best practice methods to decide which model is better? I have done 2 checks so far:

1. Compare the R-squared values of both models
2. Compare the AIC and BIC selection criteria

Thank you!